# Prototype: How can I disable the animation in TinyDropdown Plugin

Tags: javascript, animation, prototype

TinyDropdown prototype plugin works like this: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/dropdown-menu/index.html

I want to disable its animation.

**Its javascript codes:**

```
var menu=function(){
    var t=15,z=50,s=6,a;
    function dd(n){this.n=n; this.h=[]; this.c=[]}
    dd.prototype.init=function(p,c){
        a=c; var w=document.getElementById(p), s=w.getElementsByTagName('ul'), l=s.length, i=0;
        for(i;i<l;i++){
            var h=s[i].parentNode; this.h[i]=h; this.c[i]=s[i];
            h.onmouseover=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+',true)');
            h.onmouseout=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+')');
        }
    }
    dd.prototype.st=function(x,f){
        var c=this.c[x], h=this.h[x], p=h.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        clearInterval(c.t); c.style.overflow='hidden';
        if(f){
            p.className+=' '+a;
            if(!c.mh){c.style.display='block'; c.style.height=''; c.mh=c.offsetHeight; c.style.height=0}
            if(c.mh==c.offsetHeight){c.style.overflow='visible'}
            else{c.style.zIndex=z; z++; c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,1)},t)}
        }else{p.className=p.className.replace(a,''); c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,-1)},t)}
    }
    function sl(c,f){
        var h=c.offsetHeight;
        if((h<=0&&f!=1)||(h>=c.mh&&f==1)){
            if(f==1){c.style.filter=''; c.style.opacity=1; c.style.overflow='visible'}
            clearInterval(c.t); return
        }
        var d=(f==1)?Math.ceil((c.mh-h)/s):Math.ceil(h/s), o=h/c.mh;
        c.style.opacity=o; //c.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+(o*100)+')';
        c.style.height=h+(d*f)+'px'
    }
    return{dd:dd}
}();
```

**CSS codes**

```
ul.menu {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; color: #fff;}
ul.menu * {margin:0; padding:0; color: #fff;}
ul.menu a {display:block; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font:10px Verdana,Arial; }
ul.menu li {position:relative; float:left;margin-right:2px; color: #fff;}
ul.menu ul {position:absolute; top:26px; left:0; display:none; opacity:0; list-style:none; color: #fff;}
ul.menu ul li {position:relative; border:1px solid #aaa; border-top:none; width:148px; margin:0; color: #fff;}
ul.menu ul li a {display:block; padding:3px 7px 5px; background-color:#1E3B7D; color: #fff;}
ul.menu ul li a:hover {background-color:#59A1CC; color: #fff;}
ul.menu ul ul {left:148px; top:-1px}
ul.menu .menulink {border-right: 1px solid #4169E1; padding: 6px 15px; text-align: center; height: 17px; text-decoration:none; color:#fff;}
ul.menu .menulink:hover { text-decoration:none; color:#fff; }
ul.menu .menuhover {}
ul.menu .sub {background:#1E3B7D url(images/arrow.gif) 136px 8px no-repeat; color: #fff;}
ul.menu .topline {border-top:1px solid #aaa;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to scrap the javascript entirely and use [`:hover` pseudo-classes](http://w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) in your CSS instead. There are countless examples of this on the web if you only look.

Comment: do you have sample code for it? or instructions how will i do it? sorry im kinda new to js....

Comment: As a basic example consider that you need to hide then show a list within a list; First you do `ul.menu li ul {display: none;}` and then `ul.menu li:hover ul {display: block;}`. There is no javascript involved although there is a caveat, IE6 doesn't work right, but that's less important these days. I urge you to search the web for "CSS menu" and you'll see how easy it can be.